# Parsing large json

Tags: c#, json, parsing, filestream

I'm trying to parse a json file and then operate on it to insert data into a SQL Server 2008 Database.

Example:

```
var sr = new StreamReader("C:\\path to file\file.json");
var json = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(sr);
var o = JsonObject.Parse(json);
```

But I always get this error at the second line - "Timeouts are not supported on this stream."

The Json file looks like this:

```
"main":{
    "prg": [
               {
                   "Id": 1,
                   "name": "A&E",
                   more fields
               }
    "prg": [
               {
                   "Id": 2,
                   "name": "asda",
                   more fields
               }
 }
```

I need to make something like this

```
foreach (prg in main)
    entity.id = prg.id
    entity.name = prg.name
```

How can I do this and why I get that timeout exception?

**EDIT:** To better understand my question this is how I do for an XML file

```
XmlDocument sourceDoc = new XmlDocument();
sourceDoc.Load(SourcesElement2); // where SourcesElement2 is the path to my XML
XmlNodeList prg = sourceDoc.GetElementsByTagName("prg");

foreach (XmlNode item in prg)
{
    entity.Name= item.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
    ...
}
```

I have converted the XML to Json and I want to do same thing. For every "prg" node in the Json File insert a new item in the database

**EDIT2:**

This is what I've done.

```
    using (
            StreamReader stream =
                File.OpenText(
                    "C:\\path\\Sources.json")
            )
        {
            JObject sources = (JObject) JToken.ReadFrom(new JsonTextReader(stream));

            var a = sources["on"];
            var b = a["sources"];
            var c = b["prgs"];
            foreach (var item in c)
            {
                var d= item.SelectToken("prg");

                // Here d is null

            }
```

I have the same question as the one from above. For every "prg" node in the Json File insert a new item in the database. How can I do this ?   ( path to prg is  on/sources/prgs/ )

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For everyone with the same problem here is what I've done  ( NOTE: this is just an example )

By the way, thank you for everyone who tried to answer my question and I'm sorry for my mistakes.

```
        List<string> d = new List<string>();

        using (
            StreamReader stream =
                File.OpenText(
                    "C:\\path\\Sources.json")
            )
        {
            JObject sources = (JObject) JToken.ReadFrom(new JsonTextReader(stream));

            var a = sources["on"];
            var b = a["sources"];
            var c = b["prgs"];
            foreach (JObject item in c["prg"].ToList())
            {
                d.Add(item.Value<string>("name"));
            }

        }

        //part below is just for testing
        foreach (var VARIABLE in d)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Instead of using multiple variable you can write like this : sources["on"]["sources"]["prgs"]["prg"].ToList()

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you want to *serialize* the stream.

`JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(sr)`

You want to *deserialize* from the stream.

`JsonSerializer.Deserialize`

You might want to use [JsonReader](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2006/06/26/Json.NET-_2D00_-Simplifying-.NET-_3C002D003E00_-JavaScript-communication.aspx) for performance reasons.

Your XML example load the whole file in the memory - you don't want to do that for large documents. `reader.Read()` pattern is better suited for processing large files.

Comment: Thank you. I'm doing like this : JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr); But how can I do that foreach I was talking about in my question ?

Comment: Please help. I can't get it to work.  I've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it by converting that JSON object into a C# class and then applying logic to the C# object and/or use [DataTables](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable)
[Note: There are solutions online that show you would to easily pass an `Object` or `List<Object>` into a DataTable and then pass it "easily" to SQL]

The first step is still your hiccup in either solution, *how do I pull in a large JSON string from filesystem*?

if you have the JSON, use [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) and/or [jsonutils.com](http://jsonutils.com) to retrieve the classes in order to Deserialize it to your object.

```
StreamReader re = new StreamReader(@"C:\path to file\file.json");
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(re);
YourClass DeserializedObject = se.Deserialize<YourClass>(reader);
Console.WriteLine(DeserializeObject.SomeProperty);
```